# problems with use databrics dbutils-api

Tags: scala, databricks

How do we try use it?

- add dependency "com.databricks" %% "dbutils-api" % "0.0.1" to build.sbt
- wrote in code:

  `import com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils
   class Job {
       // business logic ..
       val jobResult: String = ???
       dbutils.notebook.exit(jobResult)
  }`

When we package the code into a jar we get:

```
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'NotebookUtils.class'.
[error] Could not access term common in package com.databricks.backend,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'NotebookUtils.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.databricks.backend.
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error with version '0.0.3' . Was this resolved somehow?

Comment: It's 2021, I'm trying versions 0.0.4, and 0.0.5 and the problems are still there!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is even latest ver of `dbutils-api` for now (which is 0.0.3) relies on `com.databricks.backend.common` (which is neither not part of dbutils-api nor any other public databricks libs).

```
trait NotebookUtils ... {
...
  def getContext() : com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.CommandContext
  def setContext(ctx : com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.CommandContext) : scala.Unit
}
```

While:

```
jar tvf dbutils-api_2.11-0.0.3.jar | grep backend
   439 Tue Jan 01 11:00:00 MSK 1980 com/databricks/backend/daemon/dbutils/Default.class
  1337 Tue Jan 01 11:00:00 MSK 1980 com/databricks/backend/daemon/dbutils/FileInfo$$anonfun$hashCode$1.class
  1265 Tue Jan 01 11:00:00 MSK 1980 com/databricks/backend/daemon/dbutils/FileInfo$$anonfun$hashCode$2.class
  4109 Tue Jan 01 11:00:00 MSK 1980 com/databricks/backend/daemon/dbutils/FileInfo.class
  1256 Tue Jan 01 11:00:00 MSK 1980 com/databricks/backend/daemon/dbutils/GrantInfo.class
  1480 Tue Jan 01 11:00:00 MSK 1980 com/databricks/backend/daemon/dbutils/MountInfo.class
   452 Tue Jan 01 11:00:00 MSK 1980 com/databricks/backend/daemon/dbutils/PackageGroup.class
     0 Tue Jan 01 11:00:00 MSK 1980 com/databricks/backend/
     0 Tue Jan 01 11:00:00 MSK 1980 com/databricks/backend/daemon/
     0 Tue Jan 01 11:00:00 MSK 1980 com/databricks/backend/daemon/dbutils/
```

The most probable reason is `com.databricks.backend.common` marked with provided scope in dbutils definition file (but I can't be 100% sure because this lib is not available in open source).
I would rather be intended to treat this as a bug in Databricks' libs.